# SQL - Stored Proc -- String or binary data would be truncated

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a stored proce that where for one of the parameter I am entering 1+FEU0+1663 as a varchar(50)
I am getting the following message:

```
    String or binary data would be truncated.
```

If I enter a different value it works fine. Is there a way I should be entering in 1+FEU0+1663  such that it does not pose a problem. I believe the problem may be that SQL is trying to make it into a larger number due to the + signs.

This is what I am using to execute

```
    exec usp_Insert_Lst   'E3441-NI0dd4-12', 
                              null, -- fname
                              null, -- lanme
                              null,  -- mi
                              null,  -- email
                              '1+FEU0+1663' -- PHID
```

Comment: can you post how you are trying to execute it and the stored procedure code?

Comment: Did you put that between `'`?...like this: `'1+FEU0+1663'`?

Comment: You need to show us the code of your sp and the definition of the table that you are inserting into

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce your case using only the details you gave on your question.

```
CREATE PROC usp_Insert_Lst(
    @p1 varchar(50)
    ,@p2 varchar(50)
    ,@p3 varchar(50)
    ,@p4 varchar(50)
    ,@p5 varchar(50)
    ,@p6 varchar(50)
)
AS
SELECT @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6
GO

exec usp_Insert_Lst   'E3441-NI0dd4-12', 
    null, -- fname
    null, -- lanme
    null,  -- mi
    null,  -- email
    '1+FEU0+1663' -- PHID
GO

--Result
--------------- ---- ---- ---- ---- ------------
E3441-NI0dd4-12 NULL NULL NULL NULL 1+FEU0+1663
```

Assuming you have something like this in your procedure (usp_Insert_Lst):

```
INSERT your_table (param1, fname, lanme, mi, email, PHID)
SELECT @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6
```

If this insert returns :
'String or binary data would be truncated.'

Then it can only means that your_table.fname or your_table.PHID is less than LEN('E3441-NI0dd4-12') and/or LEN(1+FEU0+1663) in size respectively.

---

Based on your comment: i have field as varchar(50)

If the stored procedure has @param1 varchar(50) and your_table.field1 varchar(50)
it could be then that the error that gives the string or binary message is between the beginning of the procedure and the insert to your_table.

```
CREATE PROC usp_Insert_Lst(
    @p1 varchar(50)
...
)
AS
...
...  <-- error to be found here
...
INSERT your_table (param1,...)
SELECT @p1,...
```

Comment: Carlos, I have the field as varchar(50) so why would it complain

Comment: Nate, check my latest edit. It could help showing the complete procedure code, although if too long I won't probably read it :)